# SQL several inner joins cause wrong SUM Result

Tags: mysql, sql

An example of my Database: (SQLFiddle link at bottom)

I have several Tables:

**Table** Login

1. User_ID (int)
2. Email (varchar)
3. Passwort
4. Seassion ID

**Table** Business

5. ID_Login_ID_Business (int)
6. NameOfCompany (varchar)
7. NameContact(varchhar)
8. ID_Location_FK (int)
9. ID_BalancesheetInput_FK (int)
10. ID_Balancesheetoutput(int)

**Table** ID_BalancesheetInput

11. ID
12. FK_Business_ID (int)
13. RessourceName (varchar50)
14. Amount (decimal)
15. Unit_Fk (int)
16. TypeOfRessource_FK(int)

**Table** Units

17. Unit_id
18. Unit

**Table** TypeOfRessource

19. ID_Type
20. Type

Sql should check all entries from Buisness where ID_Login_ID_Business(fk) equals the FK_Business_ID in BalancesheetInput, sum all amounts with the same RessourceNam,e and should simply add the typeofRessource checking the right Unit.

Example:

**Table** Business

ID, NameOfCompany, ID_BalancesheetInput_FK

- 1  Apples         1
- 2  Minisoft       2

**Table** BalancesheetInput

ID, FK_Business_ID, RessourceName, Amount, Unit_FK, TypeOFRessource_FK

- 1, 1, electricity, 100, 3, 2
- 2, 1, thermal energy, 200, 3, 2
- 3, 1, thermal energy, 150, 3, 2
- 4, 1, light fuel oil, 10,3,2
- 5, 1, Screws, 200, 3, 2
- 6, 1, Water, 200,4, 3

**Table** Units

Unit ID, Unit

- 1, pieces
- 2, Ton
- 3, kWh
- 4, m²
- 5, litre

**Table** TypeOFRessource

ID_Type, Type

- 1, Asset
- 2, Energie
- 3, Material

The following statment tries to catch the Ressources of the selected Business and calculate entries with the same name, such as electricity. They belong to one Company, but something is going wrong.

Everytime I use my sql Statment:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT "
           . "BalancesheetInput.RessourceName AS Rn, "
           . "Units.Unit AS En, "
           . "SUM(BalancesheetInput.Amount) AS TotalAmount "
           . "FROM Business"
           . "INNER JOIN BalancesheetInput ON FK_Business_ID = 1 "
           . "INNER JOIN Units ON Unit_FK = Unit_ID "
           . "INNER JOIN TypeOfRessource ON TypeOf Ressources = 2 "
           . "GROUP BY BalancesheetInput.RessourceName ");
```

**Result**:

light fuel oil  60  kWh
Energie - electricity 600   kWh
Energie - thermal energy 2100   kWh

Looks like he added 6 times the amount of each row.

**What I want as a result:**

light fuel oil  10  kWh
Energie - electricity 100 kWh
Energie - thermal energy 350 kWh

[Here is an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52367a/2) with a working version of all this.

If you need further information, just say what you need to help me solve the problem.

Comment: That GROUP BY query is invalid. Which dbms are you using? (The general GROUP BY rule is: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.")

Comment: Im using phpmyadmin with a MySQL ServerType, tables are InnoDB

Comment: Most databases would give an error when the group by doesn't have all the required fields. MySql seems to be different in that regards, which can led to confusion.

Comment: @LukStorms, older MySQL versions have that strange behavior. Newer MySQL versions don't, i.e. an error will be raised if trying to execute that query.

Comment: I see. well, then I guess Sires has an older version since that SQL was accepted by his version. the SQL Fiddle also doesn't seem to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luk Storms and I came to the same answer; here's the [SQLFiddle I made](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ded92a/1).

Tips: If you SELECT * on your JOIN, you'll [see](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52367a/11) that it's creating a table with six rows for each BalancesheetInput; one for each combination of Name of Company and Energy Type. We used WHERE to narrow down the duplicate rows. This is usually better than SELECT DISTINCT.

Also, "Screws" is miscategorized as "Energie" instead of "Materiel".

Answer (score 1):

It helps to use aliases for the tables. Also to create proper joins on the fields, instead of joining on values that should be in the where clause.

And it's best to make sure that the GROUP BY has all the fields you use in the select (ignoring those used in the functions).
Especially when using MySql.

```
SELECT  
bs.RessourceName AS Rn, 
u.Unit AS En, 
SUM(bs.Amount) AS TotalAmount 
FROM Business b
INNER JOIN BalancesheetInput bs ON bs.FK_Business_ID = b.ID
INNER JOIN Units u ON u.Unit_ID = bs.Unit_FK
INNER JOIN TypeOfRessource t ON t.ID_Type = bs.TypeOFRessource_FK
WHERE b.NameOfCompany = 'Apples' 
AND bs.RessourceName = 'electricity'
GROUP BY bs.RessourceName, u.Unit
```